# Selecting rows in an Excel file using python

Tags: python, pandas, rows, openpyxl

I have an Excel file from which I want to select sets of rows and create a new file with a worksheet for each selection. The selection is going to be based on certain values of cells in the A column. Up to now I 've written a code that provides me with a list of tuples containing the cells that will be used to set the rows I want selected. It's something like that:

`[(<Cell 'CELL'.A1>, <Cell 'CELL'.A18>), (<Cell 'CELL'.A18>, <Cell 'CELL'.A33>), (<Cell 'CELL'.A33>, <Cell 'CELL'.A46>)]`

I tried something like that:

```
df_init = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
print(df_init)
for i in tuple_list:
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    print(i[0])
    df_init=df_init[df_init['ColumnName'].between(i[1],i[0], inclusive=False)]
```

but while it gives me a result the dataframes I get are empty. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

As pandas can't load excel module in my end, using *openpyxl* instead. Just replace `.column_letter`, `.column` or `.row` with what *pandas* offers.

My strategy is getting row, column from given cell range, with those you can simply use slicing to extract cells.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

work_book = load_workbook("source.xlsx")
work_sheet = work_book.active

select_range = [
    (work_sheet['A'][1], work_sheet['A'][3]),
    (work_sheet['B'][2], work_sheet['B'][3])
]  # simulation of OP's range tuple

print(f"Will extract data in range: {select_range}\n")

for start_cell, end_cell in select_range:
    # slice from cells in work_sheet at start_cell's column.
    data = work_sheet[start_cell.column_letter][start_cell.row - 1:end_cell.row]

    # Do some data manipulation, saving etc. Just printing out result here.
    print(f"Data: {data}")
```

output:

```
Will extract data in range: [(<Cell 'Sheet1'.A2>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.A4>), (<Cell 'Sheet1'.B3>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.B4>)]

Data: (<Cell 'Sheet1'.A2>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.A3>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.A4>)
Data: (<Cell 'Sheet1'.B3>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.B4>)
```

Comment: jupiterbjy Thank you for your contribution but that's is not what I asked. What you show to me I already have. Each tuple in the tuple list represents the boundaries that define the rows I want to select and export. So for the tuple ```(<Cell 'CELL'.A1>, <Cell 'CELL'.A18>)``` I want to get the values of all the cell in rows 2 to 17 and send it to a new dataframe or excel worksheet. The tuple list already exist. If you can help me with that it would be great help. But thank you anyway for the answer

Comment: What you've got is Boundary of cell you want to extract - while my result shows extracted data from given range A1 ~ A3 and B2 ~ B3. It's easy to apply extracted cell to this schematic. I'll update answer with more detail on that.